# How to get selected ID from SQL database using textBox and update information?

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to update a databse entry under a specific `id` in my table when the users enter their ID number in a `textBox`.
At the moment it updates but updates all entries in my table except the entry containing the users ID number.

This is the code I am currently using:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DEVELOPMENT\ACCESSCONTROL;Initial Catalog=ACCESSCONTROL;User ID=sa;Password=P@55w0rd123");
        SqlCommand check_User_Name = new SqlCommand("SELECT Id FROM NewVisitor WHERE (IDNumber = @IDNumber)", con);
        check_User_Name.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDNumber", idNumber_TxtBox.Text);
        con.Open();
        int UserExist = (int)check_User_Name.ExecuteScalar();


        if (UserExist > 0)
        {
            var connetionString = @"Data Source=DEVELOPMENT\ACCESSCONTROL;Initial Catalog=ACCESSCONTROL;User ID=sa;Password=P@55w0rd123";
            var sql = "UPDATE NewVisitor SET PersonVisit = @PersonVisit, PurposeVisit = @PurposeVisit, Duration = @Duration, Disclaimer = @Disclaimer";
            try
            {
                using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString))
                {
                    using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                    {
                        command.Parameters.Add("@PersonVisit", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = personVisiting_TxtBox.Text;
                        command.Parameters.Add("@PurposeVisit", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = purposeOfVisit_CMBox.SelectedItem;
                        command.Parameters.Add("@Duration", SqlDbType.Date).Value = duration_dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
                        command.Parameters.Add("@Disclaimer", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = disclaimer_CHKBox.Checked;
                        connection.Open();
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
```

The whole table has many more fields but would like to just update the above fields within that specific ID.

Thanks

Comment: You're missing a `WHERE` clause in your `UPDATE` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `WHERE` clause on the `UPDATE` statement, telling it specifically which records to update.  It sounds like you just want to add the exact same `WHERE` clause that you have on your `SELECT`:

```
var sql = "UPDATE NewVisitor SET PersonVisit = @PersonVisit, PurposeVisit = @PurposeVisit, Duration = @Duration, Disclaimer = @Disclaimer WHERE (IDNumber = @IDNumber)";
```

And don't forget to add the paramter for it:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@IDNumber", SqlDbType.Int).Value = idNumber_TxtBox.Text;
```

You may need to convert the input value to an integer first, I'm not 100% certain (it's been a while since I've had to use ADO.NET directly).  Something like this:

```
if (!int.TryParse(idNumber_TxtBox.Text, out var idNumber))
{
    // input wasn't an integer, handle the error
}
command.Parameters.Add("@IDNumber", SqlDbType.Int).Value = idNumber;
```

Comment: Thanks,  , but it is giving an error :`Failed to Convert Parameter value from a string to a Int32`

Comment: @KeithKing: It sounds like the parameter value needs to be converted to an `int` first.  I've updated the answer.